# Create new color scheme in Vega

Tags: vega

I found that it's possible to create a new color scheme in Vega (https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/), but I don't understand where I can put this command:
`vega.scheme('basic', ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f', '#ff0', '#f0f', '#0ff']);`

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from [Schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#registering-additional-schemes) docs:

```js
// Define an interpolator function that maps from [0,1] to colors
function grey(f) {
  var g = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, Math.round(255 * f))) + '';
  return 'rgb(' + g + ', ' + g + ', ' + g + ')';
}

// Register the interpolator. Now the scheme "mygrey" can be used in Vega specs
vega.scheme("mygrey", grey)
```

Once the scheme is registered, it's time to use it.

```js
// spec is the vega specification
var color_scale = _.filter(spec.scales, function(scale) { return scale.name === 'color' })[0]
color_scale.range.scheme = "mygrey"

// el is the reference to chart container
new vega.View(vega.parse(spec))
  .renderer('svg')
  .logLevel(vega.Warn)
  .initialize(el)
  .hover()
  .run()
```

### before using `mygrey` scheme

[image: chart without mygrey color scheme]

### after using `mygrey` scheme

[image: chart with mygrey color scheme]

Comment: While this _works_ and answers the question, for any would-be implementers you should consider a different approach to picking colors: see https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/theory/ for some background